# TreeView state of collapsed/expanded items after operation javaFX

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have a problem with TreeView control in JavaFX. When I make some operation (like e.g. adding new item). Steps are:

1. I have some items of treeView expanded
2. I use contextMenu to add new item to specified node
3. Item is added to my structure (backend side)
4. TreeView is reloaded - it is displayed from the beginning (only root)

I want to have view of my TreeView like before adding item (this same items collapsed and expanded). I don't have idea how to do it. I was thinking about change the implementation of StructureNode (add boolean field isExpanded and use it but it wouldnt work - I'm opening my TreeView from file where is no information about it). Do you have some suggestions ?

Comment: If you simply modify the backend data and simply add a single item why reload the data at all? Seems like your problem would be solved if you simply add a `TreeItem` after successfully updating the backend. But if you need to reload the data you could simply create a `Map<ItemKey, Boolean>` to store the info and restore it for the new `TreeItem` structure...

Comment: Note also that it's not just the expanded state you lose by reloading the entire tree; you also lose the selection, scroll position(s), etc etc. As fabian suggests, a much better approach is just to modify the existing tree hierarchy (i.e. add a `TreeItem` to the appropriate parent if an item is added in the backend, etc.), and avoid reloading the entire structure.

Comment: @fabian @James_D I listen your comments and I've done "remove item" from backend and TreeView in same time. It is working well. My solution is that I have item which will be deleted `sctructureNode.getId()`and I have to search TreeView recursive for this item `boolean search(TreeItem<StructureNode> root, int id){
        for(TreeItem<StructureNode> c: root.getChildren()){
            if(c.getValue().getId() == id){c.getParent().getChildren().remove(c);
return true;} else {searchTreeView(c, id);}}
        return false;}` Is it good approach or I should change something ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not using the Cell edit system directly into the menu section instance you must reload the the tree from the root to show the new created cell added.
You can use an array such as byte[] (an element for each TreeView) you can store 1 or 0 to flag the view state for each tree level as e.g. 1 = shown 0=closed and perhaps if required a separate variable for the "root" byte rootState=0; or 1 for whether the tree shows.
When you place a new item into it through the back-end you then set the treeview states as shown by your memory array by alike the following code when reloading it.
e.g.

```
byte rootState=1B;
byte[] subTreeViewStates = {1B,1B,0B,1B,0B};
TreeView[] subTreeViews={number1treeView,number2treeView,number3treeView,number4treeView,number5treeView};
if((new Byte(rootState).intValue())==1){
    root.setExpanded(true); // expands that TreeView node
}else{
    root.setExpanded(false); // collapses  that TreeView node
}
for(int mnu=0; (mnu < subTreeViews.length) ; mnu++){
if((new Byte(subTreeViews[mnu]).intValue()) == 1)
subTreeViews[mnu].setExpanded(true); // expands that TreeView node
}else{
subTreeViews[mnu].setExpanded(true); // collapses  that TreeView node
}
}// end for
```

and methods for setting the memory of the view states to reshow

```
// int status is fed as either 1 or 0
byte setTreeviewsstatus(int menu,int status){
subTreeViewStates[menu]=new Integer(status).byteValue();
return subTreeViewStates[menu];
} // end method

byte rootState(int state){
rootState=new Integer(state).byteValue();
return rootState;
} // end method
```

after adding a TreeView , its an easier job to redo the array "subTreeViews" for the TreeView objects of the sub views

```
byte[] addLevelsubtree(){
int subtrees = subTreeViewStates.length + 1;
subTreeViewStates 
byte[] st = new byte[subtrees];
// copy process memory storage states to temporary local array st
for(int rdo = 0; rdo < subtrees; rdo++){
if(rdo < (subtrees-1)){
st[rdo]=subTreeViewStates[rdo];
}else{
st[rdo]=0B; // collapsed hidden
}
// recopy to reinstantiated original process view state storage array
subTreeViewStates=new Byte[subtrees];
for(int rdo2 = 0; rdo2 < subtrees; rdo2++){
subTreeViewStates[rdo2]=st[rdo2];
} // end for
return subTreeViewStates;
} // end method



TreeView[] addLevelTreeVieObj(TreeView viewtreee){
int trvw = subTreeViews.length + 1;
TreeView[] tv = new TreeView[trvw];
for(int mmx=0; mmx < (trvw-1); mmx++){
tv[mmx] = subTreeViews[mmx]; 
}
tv[(trvw-1)] = viewtreee; // add last new TreeView object element reference
//
subTreeViews = new TreeView[trvw]; // reconstruct original array larger
for(int mmxb=0; mmxb < trvw; mmxb++){
subTreeViews[mmxb] = tv[mmxb]; 
}
return subTreeViews;
} // end method
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but firstly I will check comments added to my post. If it wouldnt help I will check your solution. Have a nice day